# DuckDB R : Calculate mean and median for multiple columns

Tags: r, dbplyr, duckdb

I have a duckdb and want to calculate the means and median or multiple columns at once:

e.g.

```
#This works:
mtcars %>%
summarise(across(everything(),list(mean, median))

#This doesn't
tbl(con,"mtcars")%>%
summarise(across(everything(),list(mean, median))
```

Comment: what package version of `dbplyr` are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this is caused by how dbplyr does translation. It captures and translates the contents of each dplyr command. So when you call `summarise(across(everything(), list(mean, median)))` then `across(everything(), list(mean, median))` gets passed to the translator (which fails to translate it as intended).

If `across(everything(), list(mean, median))` was turned into one line of code for each variable (e.g. `var1 = mean(var1) ... var100 = median(var100)`) then these multiple lines could be correctly translated by dbplyr.

Perhaps later versions of dbplyr can convert `across(.)` into multiple lines of code prior to translating as @user63230's comment implies.

We should be able to do this manually following the method in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61791144/7742981) answer or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61790418/7742981) answer. Something like the following:

```r
library(rlang)

c_names = colnames(remote_table)
patterns <- parse_exprs(paste(c_names, ' = mean(', c_names, ')'))

remote_table %>%
  summarise(!!!patterns)
```

The idea is to build text strings of the commands we want executed, turn these into expressions using `parse_exprs`, and lastly to unquo them in the dplyr call (`!!!` appears to evaluate before dbplyr translation).